# Error: valueError: input arrays should have the same number of samples as target arrays. Find 1 input samples and 0 target samples

Tags: python, neural-network, keras, nlp

I'm trying to do task for system calls classification. The code below is inspired from a text classification project. My system calls are represented as sequences of integers between 1 and 340. The error I got is:

> valueError: input arrays should have the same number of samples as
>   target arrays. Find 1 input samples and 0 target samples.

I don't know what to do as it's my first time.

```
   df = pd.read_csv("data.txt") 
   df_test = pd.read_csv("validation.txt")
   #split arrays into train and test data (cross validation)
    train_text, test_text, train_y, test_y = 
   train_test_split(df,df,test_size = 0.2)
   MAX_NB_WORDS = 5700

   # get the raw text data
   texts_train = train_text.astype(str)
   texts_test = test_text.astype(str)
   # finally, vectorize the text samples into a 2D integer tensor
   tokenizer = Tokenizer(nb_words=MAX_NB_WORDS, char_level=False)
   tokenizer.fit_on_texts(texts_train)
   sequences = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(texts_train)
   sequences_test = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(texts_test)

   word_index = tokenizer.word_index
   type(tokenizer.word_index), len(tokenizer.word_index)
   index_to_word = dict((i, w) for w, i in tokenizer.word_index.items()) 
    " ".join([index_to_word[i] for i in sequences[0]])
    seq_lens = [len(s) for s in sequences]

    MAX_SEQUENCE_LENGTH = 100
    # pad sequences with 0s
    x_train = pad_sequences(sequences, maxlen=MAX_SEQUENCE_LENGTH) 
    x_test = pad_sequences(sequences_test, maxlen=MAX_SEQUENCE_LENGTH)
    #print('Shape of data train:', x_train.shape)  #cela a donnée (1,100)
    #print('Shape of data test tensor:', x_test.shape)
    y_train = train_y
    y_test = test_y
    print('Shape of label tensor:', y_train.shape)
    EMBEDDING_DIM = 32
    N_CLASSES = 2

    y_train = keras.utils.to_categorical( y_train , N_CLASSES )
    sequence_input = Input(shape=(MAX_SEQUENCE_LENGTH,), dtype='float32')

    embedding_layer = Embedding(MAX_NB_WORDS, EMBEDDING_DIM,
                    input_length=MAX_SEQUENCE_LENGTH,
                    trainable=True)
    embedded_sequences = embedding_layer(sequence_input)

    average = GlobalAveragePooling1D()(embedded_sequences)
    predictions = Dense(N_CLASSES, activation='softmax')(average)

    model = Model(sequence_input, predictions)
    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
      optimizer='adam', metrics=['acc'])
    model.fit(x_train, y_train, validation_split=0.1,
    nb_epoch=10, batch_size=1)
    output_test = model.predict(x_test)
    print("test auc:", roc_auc_score(y_test,output_test[:,1]))
```

Comment: Print the output shapes of the feature and the label arrays. Attach the output with the question.

Comment: shape of label tensor (0,1)                                                                                          y_train.shape[0] = 0               , x_train.shape[0] = 1                                                    X_train display:    [1 4 6 7 7 ......]                                                                                  Y_train display : [ ]

Comment: when I remove this line : #y_train = keras.utils.to_categorical( y_train , N_CLASSES ) The error is changed to : ValueError : Error when checking target : expected dence_1 with shape (2,), but got array with shape (1,). Which means , there is again a problm in shapes.

Comment: Don't remove that line. See, 0 samples in y_train and 1 sample in x_train. Both should have 1 number of samples.

Comment: but I dont know why, the defenition of x_train and y_train was by the same method here:   train_text, test_text, train_y, test_y = 
   train_test_split(df,df,test_size = 0.2)       . is there a problem with this  cause, in the program I found first (the original one) the two first parameters of the train_test_split function was different : df[0] , df[1], cause the data set was in columns, but in my case, the dataset is a sequences of integers .

Comment: `train_text, test_text, train_y, test_y =  train_test_split(df,df,test_size = 0.2)` is not correct. The first parameters specify features, and second specify labels only. You are passing `df` for both which is not correct